# Between group difference in mean values for all numeric variables

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, data-manipulation

I am trying to calculate trying to calculate the difference in mean values between two groups across multiple numeric variables. For instance, if I had the following data:

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2 versicolor
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 versicolor
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
```

I would like to subtract, for instance, the mean values of 'versicolor' from the mean values of 'setosa', and save this as a new dataframe.

Result looking something like this:

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    
1          0.1         0.3          0.18         0.0
```

I would really like to do this using dplyr, which I am currently learning. Also, ideally, the solution could be applied to a much larger dataframe (100's of variables) and could specifically select numeric variables to apply the function to.

If you could break down the code somewhat line by line that would be really excellent.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

There are many possible ways to do this and structure the output like you want it. One option is to re-structure the data frame to long/wide and bring it to columnar form, and then simply subtract the columns you want, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

iris1 %>% 
 group_by(Species) %>% 
 summarise_all(list(mean)) %>% 
 pivot_longer(cols = Sepal.Length:Petal.Width) %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = Species, values_from = value) %>% 
 mutate(versicolor_setosa = setosa - versicolor)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 4
>   name         setosa versicolor versicolor_setosa
>   <chr>         <dbl>      <dbl>             <dbl>
> 1 Sepal.Length   4.90       4.8             0.1000
> 2 Sepal.Width    3.4        3.1             0.300 
> 3 Petal.Length   1.43       1.35            0.0833
> 4 Petal.Width    0.2        0.2             0
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do it with `dplyr`:

```
iris %>%
  filter(Species %in% c("versicolor", "setosa")) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise_all(mean) %>%
  summarise_at(-1, diff)

# A tibble: 1 x 4
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
1        0.930      -0.658         2.80        1.08
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was reaching for! Could you please fill me in on what exactly is going on with the 'summarise_at' function here?

Comment: Excellent! summarise_at(-1, diff) applies the diff function to all columns except the first one (which is the group). You could also write summarise_at(vars(-Species), diff)

Answer (score 1):

With `purrr` (which is part of the `tidyverse`, like `dplyr`), if you always substract the same groups, you could write this:

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  select(-Species) %>% 
  map_df(~{
    mean(.x[iris$Species=="setosa"])-mean(.x[iris$Species=="versicolor"])
  })
```

From the iris dataset, you remove the Species column, then, for each other column, you subtract the means.

> ```
> # A tibble: 1 x 4
>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
>          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
> 1       -0.930       0.658        -2.80       -1.08
> ```

This is like writing this for each column:

```
mean(iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Species=="setosa"])-mean(iris$Sepal.Length[iris$Species=="versicolor"])
```

Beware that you don't use any `filter` function before the map call, else the results might be wrong.